# How to perform annotation in sentiment analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, annotations, sentiment-analysis

I collected some reviews on Books, DVD, Mobile, and Camera from www.amazon.com. I converted reviews with 1 star as negative and 5 stars as positive. The ratio of negative and positive reviews are 1:5. The collected reviews are converted into Document-Term-Matrix and few features were selected using chi-square feature subset selection method and some our proposed feature selection methods. We employed some classification algorithms like MLP, SVM, DT, etc to classify the samples. I reported the result under 10-fold cross-validation framework.

In order to compare our results with baseline, the reviewers asked me to perform the human evaluation to compare our results. How to perform annotation here? Whether we should employ annotators on randomly selected samples to compare our results or we should perform annotation for all samples?

My professor is asking to perform annotation of all samples and then divide the dataset into 10 folds, then calculate the average of an accuracy of 10-folds of annotators response to comparing our result?

I found some literature, they are performing annotation on randomly selected samples. Any reference suggested in this regard would be quite helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read about `mechanical turk` thats whats is being asked from you. spoiler alert: You will need some money to treat your friends.

Comment: I think they ask this because, as you created this data set, there is no other point of reference, no ground truth or third party method to compare with. If you cannot get people to do this task, maybe you should run your method over other public data sets for which many papers have already reported results.

Comment: But I want to know that whether I need to perform annotation on all samples or randomly selected samples are fine.